# Issues with the blood pressure case study in Hadley Wickham's book ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I am dealing with this problem several days. I have downloaded Hadley Wickham's book called ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis and I practice this problem. I want to tidy my data but all come in one column and I do not know how to separate what inside the table. I am familiar with the tidy data principles (variables in columns, observations in rows and values in cells), but I do not understand what I do wrong. Any help?
Thank you

```
bpd <- readr::read_table(
    "name age start week1 week2 week3
Anne 35 2014-03-27 100/80 100/75 120/90
Ben 41 2014-03-09 110/65 100/65 135/70
Carl 33 2014-04-02 125/80 <NA> <NA>
", na = "<NA>")
```

Comment: Use `read_table2`, it allows any number of whitespace characters between columns.

Comment: Didn't work that .. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: `read_table2` works with me but only when I remove the spaces from the beginning of the lines. I will post as an answer exactly what does work.

Answer (score 0):

Function `readr::read_table2` works with me but only when I remove the spaces from the beginning of the lines. The following is exactly what I ran and worked. Note that the variable assignment `bdp <-` is in a separate code line, in order not to mess up RStudio's automatic code formatting.

```
bdp <-
readr::read_table2(
"name age start week1 week2 week3
Anne 35 2014-03-27 100/80 100/75 120/90
Ben 41 2014-03-09 110/65 100/65 135/70
Carl 33 2014-04-02 125/80 <NA> <NA>
", na = "<NA>")

bdp
## A tibble: 3 x 6
#  name    age start      week1  week2  week3 
#  <chr> <dbl> <date>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 Anne     35 2014-03-27 100/80 100/75 120/90
#2 Ben      41 2014-03-09 110/65 100/65 135/70
#3 Carl     33 2014-04-02 125/80 NA     NA
```

It also works if I write a file with the data, removing the quotes.

```
bdp2 <- readr::read_table2(file = "testdata.txt", na = "<NA>")
identical(bdp, bdp2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**File contents.**

Filename: `"testdata.txt"`

```
name age start week1 week2 week3
Anne 35 2014-03-27 100/80 100/75 120/90
Ben 41 2014-03-09 110/65 100/65 135/70
Carl 33 2014-04-02 125/80 <NA> <NA>
```